# Instagram gem API example -- using specific options

Tags: ruby, sinatra, instagram-api

I'm currently learning how to use Instagram's API and have been playing around with the example provided on github: https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem

I've cloned their sinatra app and it runs fine. However, I want to be able to use every option provided, for example, user search.

The only photo feeds that I've gotten to work has been user_recent_media as shown below and media_popular. I did so by simply swapping the two methods.

Instagram's API shows a simple puts method in their example. How exactly can I get that to work so that I can use all their options such as search, location_recent_media, follows, etc.? What code in that example needs to be changed?

```
# Search for users on instagram, by name or username
puts Instagram.user_search("shayne sweeney")

# Get a list of media close to a given latitude and longitude
puts Instagram.media_search("37.7808851,-122.3948632")
```

---

```
get "/feed" do
  client = Instagram.client(:access_token => session[:access_token])
  user = client.user

  html = "<h1>#{user.username}'s recent photos</h1>" 
  for media_item in client.user_recent_media
    html << "<img src='#{media_item.images.thumbnail.url}'>"
  end
  html
end
```